# Помощь с функциией PHP

Tags: php

Задание:
Сделайте функцию, которая будет принимать число, а возвращать это число прописью.
Худо-бедно вымучил из себя эту функцию, но не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы она работала корректно. С числами, все цифры которых больше 0 всё работает как надо, проблемы начинаются там, где это не так.

```
function convertStringNum($num) {
    $arr = str_split((string)$num,1);
    $a = $arr[0];
    $b = $arr[1];
    $c = $arr[2];
    $arr1 = [$a*100, $b*10, $c];
    $fromC = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    $toC = array('один', 'два', 'три', 'четыре', 'пять', 'шесть', 'семь', 'восемь', 'девять');
    $fromB = array(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90);
    $toB = array('десять','двадцать','тридцать','сорок','пятьдесят','шестьдесят','семьдесят','восемьдесят','девяносто');
    $fromA = array(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900);
    $toA = array('сто', 'двести', 'триста', 'четыреста', 'пятьсот', 'шестьсот', 'семьсот',' восемьсот', 'девятьсот');
    
    $str1 = str_replace($fromA, $toA, $arr1[0]);
    $str2 = str_replace($fromB, $toB, $arr1[1]);
    $str3 = str_replace($fromC, $toC, $arr1[2]);
    return $str1 .' '. $str2 .' '. $str3;
}
echo convertStringNum('322');
```

Comment: зачем вам какие то мудреные манипуляции с `str_replace`, если можно просто вывести `{$toA[$a]}} {$toB[$b]} {$toC[$c]]}}` ?

Comment: @teran Простите мне моё невежество, я ещё новичок, но я не понял что вы имеете в виду. Не могли бы вы объяснить немного подробнее, как вы предлагаете это сделать?

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/PzIA5ZkFRbE93Qnis5hnyQ но, тут конечно до корректного решения крайне далеко, просто сокращенный вариант того, что есть у вас.

Comment: @teran Спасибо большое, я как раз дошёл до того, чтобы обозначить 0 как ' ' (paiza.io/projects/dyT_sxebOV2ECdwIhw7Lcg?language=php) , но ваша запись выглядит куда проще, я не знал, что так можно. теперь в целом, если записывать 2 как 002 или 22 как  022, то код работает, хотя как убрать этот костыль я даже примерно не представляю.

Comment: теперь думать,  как сделать, чтобы `111` было `сто одиннадцать`, а не `сто десять один` )

Comment: @teran действительно, как-то об этом не подумал. Может задать условие с помощью if?

Answer (score 0):

```
$fromC = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$toC = array('один', 'два', 'три', 'четыре', 'пять', 'шесть', 'семь', 'восемь', 'девять');
```

может следует добавить в $fromC 0 - $toC "ноль" ?